# My jQuery navigation menu slides up too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, navbar

I have a navigation menu. Child ul Sliding down when it's parent li is hovered with the mouse. It also slides up when the mouse exits. However, I am trying to get my first and 2nd sub-menu to delay by 1 second before it slides up. I want the child ul to remain open for 1 second after the mouse leaves. But, it is still sliding up immediately. What's missing in my code?

Here is the link to my Code.
https://jsfiddle.net/naeemrind/ptbzwrzu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu ul li").hover(function(){
            $(this).find(".one").stop().slideToggle(400)
        });
    });

     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu ul ul li").hover(function(){
            $(this).find(".two").stop().slideToggle(400)
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not provided a 'handlerOut' function for the hover() so it uses the same function for both hover-in and hover-out.

https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Change your code to:

```
$("#menu ul li").hover(
    function() {
         $(this).find(".one").stop().slideDown(400)
    },
    function() {
         $(this).find(".one").delay(1000).slideUp(400)
    });
});
```

Comment: **Thank You** :) I am new to Javascript and JQuery.

Comment: But now i am having another **issue**. If the pointer enters the ul for 5 times, it slides Up and Down exactly 5 times. And this is very annoying.

Comment: You need to tell `stop` to clear the queue: `.find(".one").stop(true, false).slideDown(400)`  https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Yes its working now. But I can't figure out why the texts are showing even when I hover over the gallery very fast. The li items inside the gallery are blinking, but there background is working fine after the stop function.

Comment: I just Figured out the issue. I had used another stop function after slideUp. Now its working exactly as I wanted:)